# Antd with formik setFieldValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, formik

There is a Antd table with data, when i click to button "Change", the entire line with data is passed to the function in the form of an object, now it remains to insert data into the fields, but I can't, what should I do?

**How set data to antd input using outside function?**

I can do it with .map (), but it seems more appropriate to me to use formik

[image]

[image]

```js
const BankForm = (props) => {
        const [form] = Form.useForm();
        //show close form
        const columns = [
      ...MY columns
          {
            title: "Действие",
            key: "action",
            fixed: "right",
            render: (text, record) => (
              <Space size="middle"

              I clink to Button and all data of row go to ChangeBank(record)

                <a onClick={() => ChangeBank(record)}> Изменить</a>
            
              </Space>
            ),
          },
        ];
        const formik = useFormik({
          initialValues: {
            name_bank: "",
         
          },
          validate,
          onSubmit: (values) => {
          },
        });
      //my function to set data to form
        let ChangeBank = (record) => {
          formik.setFieldValue("name_bank", record.name_bank);
        };

        return (
            <div className={clas.tableBlock_header}>
      my form
         
              <Form
                form={form}
                layout="vertical"
                hideRequiredMark
                onFinish={formik.handleSubmit}
              >
                    <Form.Item
                      name="name_bank"
                      label="Название банка"
                      rules={[{ required: true, message: "Введите название банка" }]}
                    >
                      <Input value={formik.values.name_bank} name="name_bank" />
                    </Form.Item>
              </Form>
        );
      };
```

Comment: Just remove prop `name="name_bank"` from `<Form.Item`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Почему так происходит?

Comment: Скорей всего из за конфликта с `formik`, когда задан `name="name_bank"` для `Form.Item`  работает `setter` встроенный, но ты в `value`  передал `value='{formik.values.name_bank}`. В `antd Form` есть метод чтобы программно задать поля `form.setFieldsValue` тогда не нужно задавать `value` для инпута

Comment: `<Form.Item name="name_bank" ...> <Input /></Form.Item>` а в методе `ChangeBank` делай `form.setFieldsValue({name_bank: record.name_bank});` а `formik`  вообще его убери он и не нужен здесь разве что для удобной валидации

Comment: Example without `formik` https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-glitter-6wd49

Comment: Docs for validation rules https://ant.design/components/form/#Rule

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Появилась другая проблема, если я уберу все атрибуты у Input и оставлю <Form.Item name="name_bank" rules={}>, валидация работает хорошо, но теперь при form.setFieldsValue в Input не попадает значение. А если оставлю как было то валидация не работает.

Comment: Вывод, нужно убирать `formik` и делать как я показал в примере выше

Comment: Просто если использовать `formik` тебе нужно и валидацию делать на нем. Хотя в самом `Form.Item` есть все чтобы ее реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set values in antd form fields with formik, dont give the name Form.item

AND if you want use antd with formik, and you need validaite your inputs just download **Yup**. Dont use antd menthods.
[Yup with formik](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation)

```
          <Form
            form={form}
            layout="vertical"
            hideRequiredMark
            onFinish={formik.handleSubmit}
          >
                <Form.Item
                 
                  label="Название банка"
                  rules={[{ required: true, message: "Введите название банка" }]}
                >
                  <Input value={formik.values.name_bank} name="name_bank" />
                </Form.Item>
          </Form>**strong text**
```